# Javascript implementation of the Word Tree visualization

Tags: javascript, visualization, raphael, data-visualization

Does anyone know of a Javascript implementation of the Word Tree visualization from ManyEyes? If not, could anyone recommend a nice svg library that would make it a breeze to implement? I'm planning on using RaphaelJS right now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be what you're looking for: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/graphic_javascript_tree.aspx. At the least, it's a start.

Also, RaphaelJS is probably the most clean of the SVG implementations, so I'd go with it if this doesn't pan out.